# threadpool executor inside processpoolexecutor RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have a processpoolexecutor into which I submit multiple disk read/write calls.
I want to create a threadpool inside every process for performance benefits.

below is my attempt to override and modify _process_worker method of concurrent.futures process.py to use with ProcessPoolExecutor. I am trying to run the function in a ThreadPoolExecutor inside  -

```
from concurrent.futures import process as process_futures
class ProcessPoolExecutor(process_futures.ProcessPoolExecutor):
    """Override process creation to use our processes"""
    def _adjust_process_count(self):
        """This is copy-pasted from concurrent.futures to override the Process class"""
        for _ in range(len(self._processes), self._max_workers):
            p = Process(
                target=_process_worker,  
                args=(self._call_queue, self._result_queue, None, None))
            p.start()
            self._processes[p.pid] = p

def _process_worker(call_queue, result_queue):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor: # starting a Threadpool
        while True:
            call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
            if call_item is None:
                # Wake up queue management thread
                result_queue.put(os.getpid())
                return
            try:
                if 1: # my changes , problem with this code
                    future = executor.submit(call_item.fn, *call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
                    future.add_done_callback(
                        functools.partial(_return_result, call_item, result_queue))
                else: # original code with only processpool as in futures process.py
                    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
            except BaseException as e:
                result_queue.put(process_futures._ResultItem(call_item.work_id,
                                             exception=e))
            else:
                result_queue.put(process_futures._ResultItem(call_item.work_id,
                                             result=r))
```

when I add a threadpoolexecutor inside processpoolexecutor , i get below error

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread '<threadedprocess._ThreadPoolExecutor object at 0x000001C5897B1FA0>_0'.
```

I understand that eventloop are not created on child threads, so its complaining of no current event loop. and so, even if i add new event loop -

```
def _process_worker(call_queue, result_queue, a, b):
  
    try:
        import asyncio
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("eexception {} ".format(e))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        while True:
            call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
            if call_item is None:
                # Wake up queue management thread
                result_queue.put(os.getpid())
                return
            try:
                if 1: # my changes , problem with this code
                   job_func = functools.partial(call_item.fn, *call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
                    
                    try:
                        
                        loop.run_in_executor(executor, job_func)
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.info("exception recvd {}".format(e))

                else: # original code with only processpool as in futures process.py
                        r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
            except BaseException as e:
                result_queue.put(process_futures._ResultItem(call_item.work_id,
                                             exception=e))
            else:
                result_queue.put(process_futures._ResultItem(call_item.work_id,
                                             result=r))
```

I get a new error -

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

how can i change _process_worker to run the work in a threadpool ?
Any suggestions please.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Please extract a minimal example from your code that demonstrates the problem. So that the question and answers are helpful for others having the similar issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have a simple problem that I want to modify a processpoolExecutor to use threads internally to call the workitems. most of the code that I pasted is from the standard module process.py( _process_worker ). I want to modify that to use threads inside. My code is part of large codebase, hence minimal example is difficult plus there are many questions on SO which ask about ideas and methods to improve without minimal example. One just needs to spend some time reading the question with open mind.

Comment: You are creating a new event loop *before* initializing the ThreadPoolExecutor.  That creates only one event loop, and assigns it to the main thread of the Process.  You need to create a new event loop for *every* thread.  Also it would be very helpful to see entire tracebacks instead of just the exception text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`asyncio.run(your_async_function_here())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) which creates new event loop and schedules the given function as a task in that event loop.